# Reason for uncommon OOP in Python?

Tags: python, oop

Instead of using common OOP, like Java and C# do with their base class `Object` or `object`, Python uses special methods for basic behaviour of objects. Python uses `__str__` which is used when the object is passed to `print`:

```
>>> class Demo:
>>>   def __str__(self):
>>>     return "representation"

>>> d = Demo()
>>> print(d)
representation
```

The same with `len`:

```
>>> class Ruler:
>>>   def __len__(self):
>>>     return 42

>>> r = Ruler()
>>> len(r)
42
```

What I would expect is something like this:

```
>>> class Ruler:
>>>   def len(self):
>>>     return 42

>>> r = Ruler()
>>> r.len()
42
```

What is the reason for using special methods indirectly instead of calling usual methods directly?

Comment: As for \_\_str\_\_, as I understand it, it is strictly equivalent to Java/C#'s toString. \_\_str\_\_ gives a textual representation of the object, which is clearly different from what print does — print the textual representation to the standard output.

Comment: Is this what you mean? http://docs.python.org/faq/design.html#why-does-python-use-methods-for-some-functionality-e-g-list-index-but-functions-for-other-e-g-len-list

Comment: @Thomas yes, that is the answer. Maybe you want to write it as an answer ...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The reason for this is explained well in the Python documentation here:

http://docs.python.org/faq/design.html#why-does-python-use-methods-for-some-functionality-e-g-list-index-but-functions-for-other-e-g-len-list

> The major reason is history. Functions
>   were used for those operations that
>   were generic for a group of types and
>   which were intended to work even for
>   objects that didn’t have methods at
>   all (e.g. tuples). It is also
>   convenient to have a function that can
>   readily be applied to an amorphous
>   collection of objects when you use the
>   functional features of Python (map(),
>   apply() et al).
>
> In fact, implementing len(), max(),
>   min() as a built-in function is
>   actually less code than implementing
>   them as methods for each type. One can
>   quibble about individual cases but
>   it’s a part of Python, and it’s too
>   late to make such fundamental changes
>   now. The functions have to remain to
>   avoid massive code breakage.

(This was answered in the comments, but needs to be shown as a real answer for the sake of future readers.)

Comment: Another [good argument](http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2011/7/9/python-and-pola/) is that functions like `len` are leading to a more consistent API.

Answer (score 3):

These aren't hooks.

They're just methods with special names.

The convention for special method names in Python is `__name__`.

The built-in len, iter, str, repr (and other) functions use ordinary methods with names that follow a special convention so that we can all be sure we've implemented the special methods properly.

The special methods have odd-looking names so that we are free to use *any* name we want without fear of collision.

---

> obj.len() would be much more intuitive to implement and use.

To you, perhaps.  To others, it may be utterly baffling.

Python has **both** method notation and function notation for many common functions.

And the function notation is preferred.

It's still OO programming.  Only the notation has been changed.

Comment: Ok, let's call it "special methods". Why is `__len__` only called indirectly? obj.len() would be much more intuitive to implement and use.

Comment: This doesn't get at the heart of his question.

Comment: @FogleBird: I'm glad you understood the heart of the question. Clearly, I couldn't understand it.

Comment: @daemon: If what you're asking simply "why does Python **also** have functional syntax?"  If so, please **update** the question to indicate that you want to know why Python has **both** methods as well as  functions that reference the methods.

Answer (score 0):

Hooks allow to redefine behavior of *standard* functions. Consider overriding `__add__()` and use standard infix `+` operator vs adding a custom `add()` and using nested calls.

Moreover, if you define `__iter__()`, you can use your object in a `for ... in` loop. Compare it to controlling a loop and advancing iteration by hand. Consider overriding `__call__()` and turning your instances into functions, as good as any other function. This gives enormous flexibility.

If you want, Java does the same with `.toString()` that works implicitly when you print the object or concatenate it to a string.

Answer (score 0):

Not a Pythonista, so this may be way off, but if I understand your question, my impression is that it's a matter of style and idiom rather than behaviour. Java, and to a lesser extent C#, are very verbose, canonical and orthogonal languages. Everything is an object (or for C#, *behaves* like one--IIRC `int.toString()` is valid), and everything your program does should be explicitly expressed.

Python is more terse, valuing convenience at the occasional expense of clarity. You'll see this in C++ as well, with implicit conversions and operating overloading. Just consider the C++ analog to your `toString()` examples:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& outstream, const Widget& rhs)
{
    return outstream << rhs.name();
}

std::cout << myWidget;
```

Comment: I think you've got a point about it being terser - Python aims for a balance between explicit and compact. But also in Python, everything inherits from `object`, and you can do `someint.__str__()` if you want (it's not recommenended, but it does the same as `str(someint)`).